# Why can't I check if an array is empty with array == []?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a question from CodeWars that is named "Count of positives/sum of negatives". It says:

> If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array

To check if the array is empty, I decided to check if it was an empty array. When I try to do:

```
if(input == [])
```

I fail the test, but if I do:

```
if(input.length == 0)
```

I pass the test. An empty array should be equal to `[]` right? Why is there a difference, and what is the difference between these two checks?

My code is as follows:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
   var a = 0;
   var b = 0;
   if (input == null) {
      return []
   }
   if (input.length == 0) {
      return []
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i] > 0) {
         a++;
      }
      if (input[i] < 0) {
         b += input[i];
      }
   }
   return [a, b]
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried `[] == []` in the console?

Comment: Try `0 == []` and `"" == []`. Both evaluate to `true`.

Comment: put first line of method,  input = input || []; and you would save lot of conditions.

Comment: Before you consider downvoting, this question does in fact show a proper amount of research and effort. Just because you think the answer is easy doesn't necessarily mean it is. JavaScript equalities can be notoriously tricky, so cut new developers a little slack.

Comment: It is like comparing two empty boxes. Empty box in your left hand looks just like empty box in your right hand, but they are not the same object. However, they are both empty (`length` is 0).

Comment: @smarx That is true, but falls into the category of arcana, and is wholly irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @torazaburo It's relevant if one of the tests is passing in the value `0` or an empty string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that arrays *are objects*. When you compare two objects, you compare their references. Per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> #### Equality (==)
>
> If **both operands are objects**, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Since two instances of arrays don't necessarily have the same reference, the check fails. Just try this in the console:

```
> [] == []
false
```

Two arrays seemingly with the same content (or lack thereof) are not equal. That's because content is not checked, but reference. These two arrays are separate instances and refer to different places in memory, thus the check evaluates to false.

On the other hand, just checking the length, and if it is zero checks if the array is empty or not. The `length` property signifies the amount of content in an array<sup>1</sup> and is part of every array. Since it is part of every array and reflects the amount of data in the array, you can use it to check if the array is empty or not.

---

<sup>1</sup> Beware, though, of [*sparse arrays*](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html) as mentioned by [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381669/why-cant-i-check-if-an-array-is-empty-with-array/44381713#comment75764757_44381713) in the comments. Such arrays can be created with `new Array(N)` which will give you an empty array, but with length N.

Comment: "[length] *…always reflects the amount of data in the array*" only when `length==0`, e.g. `new Array(19)` creates an empty array with length 19. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yep, I forgot about sparse arrays. I've added a note, thanks

Comment: @AndrewLi Great answer. Would the following be an acceptable replacement for OP? `((!input) == [])`

Comment: @Zze No. When objects are coerced to booleans, they will always be coerced to true regardless of content. It will not give the correct result for arrays that aren't empty.

Answer (score 0):

null has no length

```
  if (input === null || input.length === 0 ) {
    return [];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] res2 = new int[] { };

 if (input == null || input.Length == 0)
       return res2;
```

This code will solve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).